# Permanently trim Live Photos

Tags: ios, photos

If you're editing a Live photo, you can trim a section off of the beginning, but if you re-open the editing mode, the trimmed section will still be there.

As a result, if you try to use the Bounce or Loop mode, they'll start at a part of the clip you've supposedly removed. Is there a way to bake in the trim, so that it doesn't remember being longer?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround! By saving the image to Files, and then re-importing it to Photos, the length gets cropped to your desired one.

Comment: This only saved the photo as a still for me